# Querying data with a time-based filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a search to return syslog messages with critical terms in them. I also want to restrict the time period. Based on the following documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/full-text-queries.html

I thought I would be able to combine query and filter to retrive these documents:

```
GET /_search {
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "message",
            "query" : "error OR warn OR fatal OR fail"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1hr"
        }
    }   
}}
```

This fails to parse and I'm not 100% clear why. Has anyone found a good document that shows how to combine query with a time-based range filter? I've been scouring the web but my searches haven't turned up anything useful. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a bool query

```
GET /_search
      {
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
                {
                   "query_string":{
                      "default_field":"message",
                      "query":"error OR warn OR fatal OR fail"
                   }
                },
                {
                   "range":{
                      "timestamp":{
                         "gte":"now-1hr"
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tested your example and it's not returning any documents. If I run the same query from the Kibana Discover tab I get a number of results. Heading off to read through the bool documentation to see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Do you have some example documents you can post?

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. I read through the "Range Query" documentation and the matching issue is due to a timezone mismatch. Adjusting that allows it to work flawlessly! Huge thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Nice, but you should move the `range` constraint to a `bool/filter` as it doesn't contribute to the ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "terms" query, that's your "OR"

```
GET /_search
      {
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
               {
                 "terms": {
                   "message": [
                     "error",
                     "warn",
                     "fatal",
                     "fail"
                   ]
                 }
               },
                {
                   "range":{
                      "timestamp":{
                         "gte":"now-1hr"
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, too, but you're missing a comma between the two constraints and the `range` one should be in a `bool/filter`instead.

Comment: I added the comma, thanks.  There is no need for the range to be in a separate bool/filter.

Comment: There's no reason for it to be in `bool/must` either since it doesn't contribute to scoring. Best practice is to put yes/no constraints in `bool/filter`

Comment: I get what you're saying now.  Thanks for the additional info.